# Query to get all column famlies data from hbase

Tags: sql, hbase

Is there a way to get all data from hbase database from all column families without mentioning the key. Actually I want to know about query to get all data.

Comment: all data from a table or all data from a database?

Answer (score 1):

This post describes how to dump a table: http://www.rotanovs.com/hbase/hbase-importexport/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a scan on the tables. If you have HBase shell, run it, and then run

```
scan 'tablename'
```

Are you looking for a way to do this on all tables in the database?